# Motivations for the axioms of Galois category

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, galois-theory

We know that any Galois category is equivalent to the category of  finite $\pi$-sets where $\pi$ is a unique profinite group. I think axioms for a Galois category were choosen so that the above theorem becomes true. But how would someone guess exactly axioms will give us the correct answer? Is there some kind of motivation behind choosing each axiom?

SGA I, Le groupe fondamental : généralités. [Exposé V](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0206203v2.pdf).

Comment: What are the axioms for a Galois category?

Comment: Yes. It should satisfy axioms that makes it looks a like a category of finite coverings.